# QKeyEvent handling non-latin layouts

Tags: c++, qt, non-latin, qkeyevent

What is the way to handle non-latin keys pressed with Qt?

For example, for 'W' key pressed QKeyEvent::key() returns 87, but for 'Ц' - the same key in the russian layout - it returns 1062.

So I can't use constants like Qt::Key_W for checking which key has been pressed: they won't work if a user switches the layout.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of a key depends on the currently selected layout. What you observe is correct. If you pressed that key in any other application, you wouldn't get a W, but a Ц (C).

A given key means `Qt::Key_W` only if it's in a layout that produces the Roman `W`.

If you intend to refer to physical keys, you can try using `QKeyEvent::nativeScanCode()` and/or `QKeyEvent::nativeVirtualKey()`. These values are platform-dependent, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
As it turned out, only `QKeyEvent::nativeScanCode()` returns proper (the same) values for the same keys in different layouts. But if they are platform specific, I can't imagine, how I can use them...

Also, according to Qt docs (about `QKeyEvent::nativeScanCode()`):
"Note: On Mac OS/X, this function is not useful, because there is no way to get the scan code from Carbon or Cocoa. The function always returns 1 (or 0 in the case explained above)."

So I'm thrilled what the way so many programs handle key events?..

Comment: @mvlabat Once you let the user program the key<->function assignments, it's not necessary anymore to be stuck to any preset scan codes. That's how everyone else deals with it. Your application can have the `W` default, and you can simply assign more keys to the same function. On a Cyryllic keyboard, someone could also assign the Ц to that function. Just make sure that you can assign more than one key to a function! Basically you have to reformulate your problem.